# Let $A$ be a Hermitian square complex matrix of size $n$ then $\langle Ax,x\rangle=0$ for all $x \in \Bbb C^n$. Then $A=0$

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $A$ be a Hermitian square complex matrix of size $n$ then $\langle Ax,x\rangle=0$ for all $x \in \Bbb C^n$. Then $A=0$

I need a **hint** to prove it, if possible

Thank you

Comment: no that was a different question

Comment: Why was it different? It implies this one, right? A hint for a proof was given there, by the way. I will copy it to this question now.

Comment: In that question I asked if the condition that A is Hermitian is really necessary but that's it.. after trying to prove it myself I did one direction and couldn't do the other so I asked for a hint in this question

Comment: oh so sorry I didn't know that people could still post answers after I accept one.. so I didn't check for other answers in that post

Comment: I really didn't ask for a proof there so why would I have rechecked after accepting the answer to my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A,$ there exists $x\ne 0$ vector of $\mathbb{C}^n$ such that $Ax=\lambda x$. So,
$$0=\langle Ax,x\rangle=\langle \lambda x,x\rangle=\lambda\langle x,x\rangle=\lambda \underbrace{\left\|{x}\right\|^2}_{\ne 0}\Rightarrow \lambda=0.$$ As $A$ is hermitian, there exists an unitary matrix $U\in\mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$ such $A=U^*\underbrace{D}_{0}U$. So, $A=0.$

Comment: Very good! @Sweetstack, this is exactly the former answer to the duplicate question (deleted now there).

Comment: oh ok thank you so much @DietrichBurde

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

1) All Hermitian matrix can be diagonalized;

2) if $\lambda$ is a eigenvalue then $<Ax,x>=\lambda |x|^2=0 \rightarrow \lambda =0$.

Can you finish?

Comment: @ Dietrich Burde: Your answer was published almost at the same time than mine. (+1)